# Why is there a difference in magnitude response between scipy.filtfilt and scipy.lfilter?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I was trying to filter a signal using the scipy module of python and I wanted to see which of lfilter or filtfilt is better.
I tried to compare them and I got the following plot from my mwe

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frequency = 100.             #cycles/second
samplingFrequency = 2500.         #samples/second
amplitude = 16384   
signalDuration = 2.3
cycles = frequency*signalDuration

time = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi*cycles, signalDuration*samplingFrequency)
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(time.shape[-1])
inputSine = amplitude*np.sin(time)
#Create IIR Filter
b, a = sp.iirfilter(1, 0.3, btype = 'lowpass')

#Apply filter to input
filteredSignal = sp.filtfilt(b, a, inputSine)
filteredSignalInFrequency = np.fft.fft(filteredSignal)
filteredSignal2 = sp.lfilter(b, a, inputSine)
filteredSignal2InFrequency = np.fft.fft(filteredSignal2)

plt.close('all')
plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Sine filtered with filtfilt')
plt.plot(freq, abs(filteredSignalInFrequency))
plt.subplot(122)
plt.title('Sine filtered with lfilter')
plt.plot(freq, abs(filteredSignal2InFrequency))

print max(abs(filteredSignalInFrequency))
print max(abs(filteredSignal2InFrequency))
plt.show()
```

Can someone please explain why there is a difference in the magnitude response?

Thanks a lot for your help.[image: lfilt vs filtfilt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your graphs shows that the signal filtered with `filtfilt` has a peak magnitude of 4.43x10<sup>7</sup> in the frequency domain compared with 4.56x10<sup>7</sup> for the signal filtered with `lfilter`. In other words, the signal filtered with `filtfilt` has an peak magnitude that is 0.97 that when filtering with

Now we should note that [`scipy.signal.filtfilt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html) applies the filter *twice*, whereas [`scipy.signal.lfilter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) only applies it once. As a result, input signals get attenuated twice as much. To confirm this we can have a look at the frequency response of the Butterworth filter you have used (obtained with `iirfilter`) around the input tone's normalized frequency of `100/2500 = 0.04`:

[image]

which indeed shows an that the application of this filter does causes an attenuation of ~0.97 at a frequency of 0.04.